# Who is the naked lady in Big fish?

Tags: movie, big-fish

I have just finished watching *Big Fish (2003)*. It is a really great movie but left me puzzled over the significance of *The Naked Lady.*

Spectre was a real town, Jenifer lived there and Edward also reconstructed that town. He might have only made things up like putting the shoes on wire etc. But here my **Question** is who was the naked lady in that lake Edward saw while his first stay in Spectre and tried to save her from snake bite, and what was her role or significance in the movie, even if she was one of the fantasy story of Edward? She was also shown in the movie while Edward's car drowns in the thunderstorm water in the story Jennifer tells Will  and then again in the end while Edward died in the river. Just after watching naked lady first time, Edward see Jennifer (as a baby) who seem to know something about her.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call Big Fish sci-fi/fantasy.

Comment: @Rori Its not sci-fi, but  I checked its genre, according to wiki its , fantasy drama

Comment: First off, wikipedia is not a reliable measure of what is or isn't considered "fantasy". Second, most of this is unnecessary. Finally, as-is, you have multiple questions here merged into one. Either condense them down into a reasonable all-in-one version, or ask them as separate questions.

Comment: I do not think Big Fish is fantasy, regardless of what Wikipedia says (and if you read the Talk Page, there isn't a consensus there...). To me Big Fish is a drama film with slight fantastical elements, all conveniently contained in tall tales. I don't know if that's on-topic here.

Comment: @phantom42 I tried to edit and cut all the extra stuff. I guess asking two question from same movie should be ok, as answers might be connected. Please lemme know if it still needs improvement

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth [Sometimes](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7074/when-are-we-okay-with-multiple-questions-in-one), but in this case I think you should split them

Comment: I personally think it fits fantasy well. It's left mildly ambiguous as to how much of Will's father's story was the truth and how much of it was enhanced reality.

Comment: It should be ok now. I guess. Please check.

Comment: @SeanDuggan I don't know that I'd call it "fantasy" in the sense that we mean on this site; it seems more like Will's father is just making things up, which means they're not true *in-universe* either...

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield it doesn't really matter - if we classified movies like that Princess Bride wouldn't qualify as fantasy due to not being true in the films true story of grandfather reading the book

Comment: I had to look up Big Fish to find out what the heck we were talking about. Might be worth a watch.

Answer (score 9):

### Who is the River woman<sup>1</sup>?

Dialogue with Jenny suggests that she's not really a "woman", but rather a sort of hallucination; Jenny's dialogue suggests that "she" represents something the observer wants, but can't have:

> **Jenny** (matter-of-factly) It's not a woman, it's a fish. No one ever catches her.
>
> Given the day he's had so far, Edward isn't inclined to follow up on the issue. He starts to wade back to the bank.
>
> **Jenny (cont'd)** Fish looks diff'rent to diff'rent people. My daddy said it looked like the coon dog he had when he was a kid, back from the dead.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Big Fish* (2003)](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Big-Fish.html)</sub></sup>

The idea of the "uncatchable lady fish" crops up a few times throughout the movie, most often in connection with Edward's wife Sandra; in his death scene, Edward himself draws a comparison between the two women:

> But one face is missing from the crowd -- Sandra. Will turns to see she's already standing in the river beside them.
>
> The reflection of the light off the water gives Sandra an unearthly glow. She's more tranquil and more beautiful than we've ever seen her.
>
> **Edward** My girl in the river.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Big Fish* (2003)](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Big-Fish.html)</sub></sup>

### What does the River Woman represent?

It varies, depending on when she appears. In his blog John August, who wrote the screenplay, says that in Spectre she represents Edward's sexual awakening (emphasis mine):

> Spectre is supposed to be a lot of different things at once. It’s the mythical town that Edward was hoping to find, but he found it too quickly. It’s a poor Southern town subject to liens and bankruptcy, which only Edward can save. **It’s the location of Edward’s sexual awakening (the girl in the river)** and his near-affair (with Jenny Hill). If anything, it’s a beautiful trap that Edward stumbles into twice.
>
> <sup><sub>[johnaugust.com "Metaphors in Big Fish" February 4, 2004](http://johnaugust.com/2004/metaphors-in-big-fish)</sub></sup>

In another post, August has a transcript of his first meeting with Daniel Wallace, author of *Big Fish: A Novel of Mythic Proportions*, on which the movie was based. According to Wallace, the River Woman represents Edward's sexual awakening, but in some contexts represents an aspect of his youth, and serves as a divine protector:

> [In Spectre] I was using her as a sexual initiation, in a way, without the sex, or this awareness of the other sex, whatever. And she wasn’t going to appear again in the book. I didn’t think of her as being a reappearing character. But she came back when he was leaving Ashland [Ashton, in the movie]. When he went down to the lake, it seemed to make sense that she would be there to say goodbye to him, because she represented part of his youth — a very simple, unadorned, beautiful part — and he was leaving all that behind. And then later she comes in when the ship is sinking, and saves his life. I actually did research to find out how a boat sinks, what happens and everything. I knew he jumped overboard and went underwater, and there would be all this oil on the surface, and people get sucked under by the boat going down, and fire, and you didn't want to get oil all over you because that would make you sink. So once he was underwater, she just came back. Then, Greek myths, heroes, usually have a goddess that watches over them and protects them, like Athena was Odysseus’ protector. I think it was Athena. You know how it goes, some of the Gods are against them, and there’s always one that is for them and saves them all the time, and that was sort of a take on that.
>
> <sup><sub>[johnaugust.com "Transcript of my first meeting with Daniel Wallace" September 9 2004](http://johnaugust.com/2004/transcript-of-my-first-meeting-with-daniel-wallace)</sub></sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm calling her this over "Naked lady in the river" because that's how actress [Bevin Kaye is credited](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1508744/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t60#actress-tt0319061) for the role.

Answer (score 1):

**She is a mermaid, and a divine protector and represents Edward's sexual awakening.**

The Girl in the River (from Daniel Wallace’s novel Big Fish: A Novel of Mythic Proportions) and the Naked Lady (from Tim Burton’s movie adaptation of Wallace’s novel) are the same character but perform actions differently. My answer is more aligned with the novel narrative.

In both (the novel and the movie), there are two encounters between Edward and the naked lady.

In the novel, the first encounter occurs in the chapter entitled *The Girl in the River*. The scene is a bit similar to the one in the movie with the lady bathing waist deep in the water. In the novel, after catching the snake, Edward has a brief conversation with the young naked woman. She thanks him for saving her life, and after she asks him to turn around for her to get dressed, he waits five minutes and when he turns around, she’s gone. Also, instead of a snake, Edward is grabbing a wooden stick that turns again into a snake when he throws it in the river and watches it swim away. The girl never steps out of the water because she is a mermaid. She just submerges and goes away swimming under the water.

In the movie adaptation, during the first encounter we see the rear view of the nude lady standing in water just below her lower back and when Edward approaches her and traps the snake, then, she submerges and goes away but we can briefly see her legs.

The second encounter occurs in the chapter entitled *He Goes to War* where Edward jumps from a sinking ship that has been hit by a torpedo, and starts miraculously to breathe, no with his lungs but his body, while being deep under the water. Then, he sees the same young naked lady from the river waving to him in the distance away from the ship. He begins to swim towards her under oily waters, but when he reaches the place (now crystal blue) where she is supposed to be, she's gone, and all the sudden he is in need of a breath of fresh air. She saves Edward's life by preventing him from drowning.

The second encounter in the movie, the naked lady swims around Edward's car that drowns in the thunderstorm water. Then, she swims away.

Daniel Wallace narrative in the novel, about the naked lady, describes beautifully the nature of the character, a mermaid, and her role as Wallace also tells in the interview mentioned by @Jason Baker, where the American author says: “I was using her as a sexual initiation, in a way, without the sex” and that she serves as “a divine protector”. A goddess that watches over Edward and protects him like Athena did to Odysseus.